# "Function calls are not supported." with ngc AOT compilation (angular-quickstart-lib)

Tags: angular, angular-aot

I am making my custom module with [angular-quickstart-lib](https://github.com/filipesilva/angular-quickstart-lib). And when I run integration script, it throws error:

> Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function
>   calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda
>   with a reference to an exported function (position 15:23 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving  symbol MetrikaModule.forRoot in
>   D:/Projects/Playground/ng-yandex-metrika/integration/node_modules/ng-yandex-metrika/ng-yandex-metrika.d.ts,
>   resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/Projects/Playground/ng-yandex-metrika/integration/src/ap
>   p/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in
>   D:/Projects/Playground/ng-yandex-metrika/integration/src/app/app.module.ts

My repo is [here](https://github.com/FriOne/ng-yandex-metrika/tree/possible-aot-fixes). You can see the module [here](https://github.com/FriOne/ng-yandex-metrika/tree/possible-aot-fixes/src/lib) and integration test [here](https://github.com/FriOne/ng-yandex-metrika/tree/possible-aot-fixes/integration/src/app). To run integration test there is command `npm run integration:aot`. Can anyone say why this error occurs?

There are a lot of questions on stackoverflow, but they didn't helped.
I also have seen [this](https://gist.github.com/chuckjaz/65dcc2fd5f4f5463e492ed0cb93bca60).

Comment: You should change this static forRoot to a method

Comment: @Whisher could you please clarify what do you mean? I think forRoot should be static. For example [here](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/dropdown/dropdown.module.ts). And also [this](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#configure-core-services-with-coremoduleforroot)

Comment: Look at it better static forRoot(): is a type and its not a property but a method

Comment: Don't get in, why it should be a property?